# Добавление игры в слова телеграм боту на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Итак,пишу простого разговорного бота для себя.Использую `pyTelegramBotAPI`.
Сейчас он работает таким образом, что в зависимости от **введенного слова**, отвечает заготовленными фразами. Для вариантов вопросов и ответов был создан *словарь*,а также *текстовый документ*(откуда он берет данные).

Сейчас у меня появилось желание расширить боту функционал и добавить игру в слова.

Написал ее, но столкнулся с проблемой - **как имплементировать эту функцию боту**. То есть, не получается сделать диалог в игре:

`мой ответ->ответ бота->мой ответ->ответ бота`

Он берет только первое мое сообщение, пропускает его 15 раз через функцию(стоит счетчик на 15 неправильных ответов) и останавливается.

В силу своего небогатого опыта не знаю то ли я вообще делаю и есть ли смысл имплементировать таким образом:

Функцию я скопировал в скрипт с ботом,а в хендлере передал ее вызов:

```
    counter = 0


    def recursive_input_word(word_dict: dict, word_last='', player=0) -> None:
        global counter

        if player == 0:
            try:
                word = message.text.format(int(player)).strip().lower() # ввод слова человеком
            except Exception:
                print("Упс, что-то не так.Попробуй-ка ещё раз")
        else:
            word = random.choice([k for k in word_dict.keys() if k.startswith(word_last[-1])])  # ввод слова компьютером
            print(word)

        if not (word in ('я устал', 'с меня хватит') or counter >= 15):  # выход

            if word_last and word[0] != word_last[-1]:
                counter += 1
                print('Слово должно начинаться с последней буквы предыдущего {}"{}" -> "{}"{}'.format(
                    word_last[:-1], word_last[-1], word[0], word[1:]))

            else:
                check = word_dict.get(word)  # проверка слова на существование
                if check:  # слово найдено
                    word_last = word
                    word_dict[word] = False  # пометить слово использованным
                    if word_last[-1] in ('ь', 'ъ', 'ы'):
                        word_last = word_last[:-1]
                    player = not player  # сменить игрока
                elif check is None:
                    counter += 1
                    print('Такого слова не существет.')
                else:
                    counter += 1
                    print('Слово уже было использовано в игре.')
            recursive_input_word(word_dict, word_last, player)  # рекурсия


    file = open('file2.txt', 'r')
    lines1 = file.readlines()

    with open('russian_nouns.txt') as file:
        lines = filter(bool, map(str.strip, file))  # исключить пустые строки
        words = {}.fromkeys(map(str.lower, lines), True)  # {'aqwea': True, 'aasda': True, }


    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start_message(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hey,hommies')


    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def send_text(message):
        if message.text.lower() in (opts["greeting"]):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(opts['greeting']))
        elif message.text.lower() in (opts["rude_words"]):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не обзывайся')
        elif message.text.lower() in (opts["joke"]):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(lines1))
        elif message.text.lower() in (opts["love"]):
            bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, random.choice(opts["love stickers"]))
        elif message.text.lower() in (opts["weather"]):
            observation = owm.weather_at_place('Odessa,UA')
            w = observation.get_weather()
            temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]
            answer = "В городе сейчас " + w.get_detailed_status() + '\n'
            answer += 'Температура в районе ' + str(temp) + ' градусов'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
        elif message.text.lower() == 'игра в слова':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, recursive_input_word(words))

        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Оставь меня старушка, я в печали")
```

Но так оно,естественно не работает.

А тут полный код игры в слова. Опять же, не знаю правильно или нет,но оно работает:

```
    counter = 0

    def recursive_input_word(word_dict: dict, word_last='', player=0) -> None:
        global counter

        if player == 0:
            try:
                word = input('Player_{} Введите слово: '.format(int(player))).strip().lower()  # ввод слова человеком
            except Exception:
                print("Упс, что-то не так.Попробуй-ка ещё раз")
        else:
            word = random.choice([k for k in word_dict.keys() if k.startswith(word_last[-1])])  # ввод слова компьютером
            print(word)

        if not (word in ('я устал', 'с меня хватит') or counter >= 15):  # выход

            if word_last and word[0] != word_last[-1]:
                counter += 1
                print('Слово должно начинаться с последней буквы предыдущего {}"{}" -> "{}"{}'.format(
                word_last[:-1], word_last[-1], word[0], word[1:]))

            else:
                check = word_dict.get(word)  # проверка слова на существование
                if check:  # слово найдено
                     word_last = word
                    word_dict[word] = False  # пометить слово использованным
                    if word_last[-1] in ('ь', 'ъ', 'ы'):  # убирает ь,ъ,ы с конца слов
                        word_last = word_last[:-1]
                    player = not player  # сменить игрока
                elif check is None:
                    counter += 1
                    print('Такого слова не существет.')
                else:
                    counter += 1
                    print('Слово уже было использовано в игре.')
           recursive_input_word(word_dict, word_last, player)  # рекурсия


    with open('russian_nouns.txt') as file:
        lines = filter(bool, map(str.strip, file))  # исключить пустые строки
        words = {}.fromkeys(map(str.lower, lines), True)  # {'агония': True, 'апельсин': True, }
    recursive_input_word(words)  # старт
```

Итак:

> 1.Можно ли добавить эту игру боту, чтобы это был как обычный диалог?

-бот,как дела?

-хорошо

-сыграем в слова

-давай

-яблоко

-орех

-холод

-дыра

-закончим

-спасибо за игру

-бот, расскажи шутку

> ...
>   То есть инициализировать игру простой фразой(или командой),а после ее окончания продолжить общение на другие темы.

Если есть пожелания по оптимизации кода, был бы очень благодарен за помощь!